# Finding set bits of an integer

Tags: c#, binary, decimal, bitmask

Okay, got a question. I have assembled a bit mask for options. Basically my page has a list box that allows multiple selections that stores them in a list of integers (their ID value). There are 14 total choices (so ID val 1-15). The reason I am assembling this into a bit mask is because I don't want to hard code in a number in case I want to add options to the database table (where the listbox populates from). Also, I do not want to be sending in 14 parameters to my SQL stored procedure (thus hardcoding in the number 14). I can send in this integer and deconstruction it (later step).

However, right now I need to find out which bits are set in my integer for another reason. Basically I have a property. The get assembles the bit mask from a list of integers (gotten from user selection) and returns an integer of that binary decimal value. Here is my assembled code for the building of the bitmask.

```
//optsNum is my integer list. This is the list containing the ID nums of the selections.
//so if the user selects the first, second, and fourth option, the list contains 1,2,4 (count 3)
//typeCount is an integer of the amount of options in the list box
int total = 0;
for (int c = 0; c < optsNum.Count(); ++c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= typeCount; i++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) == optsNum[c})
            total += (1 << i);
    }
}
return total;
```

So if the first, second, and fourth are set, my integer is 11. This works, I tested for all selections and it is returning the correct integer/decimal value.

Right now I need help making my set method. This needs to take the decimal/integer that I have, find out which bits are set and place those back into the list. So if I have 11 as my value, I need to put into a list of integers 1,2,4. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Related posts - [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/465053) & [What is the fastest way to count set bits in UInt32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12171584/465053) & [Counting bits set in a .Net BitArray Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5063178/465053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`BitArray` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) instead; it does the bitwise operations for you and has a simple interface.
If you will never need more than 32 booleans, you can also use the [`BitVector32` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx), which is smaller.

---

To answer your question, you need to loop over every bit (using a simple a `for` loop) and check `value & (1 << i)` to see whether the `i`th bit is set.

Comment: Is there anyway to return the position rather than the bit value? For eaxample, I am doing what you said. Position 1,2,4 is set (value 1,2,8). However, I need them to return the positions....not the value of that position. So I need my new array to list 1 2 4 not 1 2 8.

Comment: Never mind i am an idiot. I can just add the position i am in the loop to my list. WOW! terrible headache and my mind just DOES NOT want to function the day before thanksgiving holiday break.